# How to get WebSocketSession from ApplicationListener or interceptor

Tags: java, spring-websocket, sockjs

Is it possible to get session (WebSocketSession) from SessionSubscribeEvent?

```
public class SubscriberListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {

   @Override
   public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
       // how to get WebSocketSession?
   }
}
```

My WebSocketConfig extends from AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer